# SSRS Excel Export - Cannot locate the internet server or proxy server

Tags: reporting-services

I have a summary report and a detail report where I've added an action to the summary report allowing the user to click and go to the detail report.  When you click on the summary report to drill through in the browser, the detailed report renders fine.  When you export to excel and try the same action, a message pops up saying "Cannot locate the internet server or proxy server".  I've configured my SSRS instance with a SSL certificate but the link when clicking from Excel isn't https:

http://InstanceName/ReportServer?%2FMyFolderName%2FReportName&Param=ParamValue&rs%3AFormat=Excel&rs%3AParameterLanguage=

The action is configured like this:

[image]

I've tried looking at settings in BIDS and Report Server Configuration Manager but I'm not seeing anything.

Why is it working when I click on the field in my browser but not when exported to Excel and how can I fix this / get the correct URL to appear as the link in Excel?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show how the Action is configured

Comment: Hi Alan, I've added an image of the action

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting the report to Excel then it's better to set the Action to be "Go to URL".

Then in the "Select URL" field use an expression something like

```
=Globals.ReportServerUrl
+ "?/MyFoldderName/Releases+by+Agent+Detail" 
+ "&ReleaseTechnician=" + cStr(Fields!ReleaseTechnician.Value)
+ "&rc:Parameters=Collapsed"
```

I can't test the above expression for obvious reasons but you should be able to work out any issues.

Using this method ensures that the link will work in both the web portal and once exported to Excel

Comment: Hi Alan.  When using this method, in the browser I get "{serverName} server IP address could not be found."  In Excel I get "Unable to open {url}.  Cannot locate the internet server or proxy server".

Comment: I use this often so it should work fine. If the URL is not valid then either you have the wrong folder/report name in the expression or the server is simply not accessible. Try navigating to the report via the reports service rather han the web portal and see if the URL matches. Start bu going to http://yourReportServerName/reportserver from there you should see your folders. Navigae to the report you want to show and check the url for the link - compare it to what you are getting from excel.